# Is there any good option to deploy service fabric apps in parallel via vsts?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-service-fabric

I've created solution with many service fabric application types. And I want to deploy it simultaneously to my azure service fabric cluster via vsts pipeline.

I am going to write Powershell script to deploy all apps at the same time. But maybe vsts has some option to deploy different application type simultaneously?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure many private agents and run the pipeline in all the agents in parallel.

Configure pipeline with many [Deploy Service Fabric Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/service-fabric-deploy?view=vsts) task:

[image]

Press on the "Agent job", expand the "Execution plan" and choose "Multi-agent" (insert the number of your agent):

[image]